# Is it possible to declare default function parameters in TypeScript declaration files?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Visual Studio Code gives an error if I try the following inside a class in a TypeScript declaration file:

`axpy (x: Float32Array, y: Float32Array, alpha = 1.0);`

It says about the parameter alpha: "A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation."

Is there any way to show alpha's default value that I am not aware of?

Comment: You can do that with a JSDoc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Paleo. I was already afraid of JSDoc being the only option. I was hoping to avoid using JSDoc for most function, by providing clear naming and typing of methods and parameters instead (does obviously not apply to the function in the example).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the compiler is right too. The instruction `= 1.0` is about implementation and cannot be in a definition. You could do `= new SomeClass()` or `= someFunction()`.